# constructing a Unicode string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I'm trying to construct and print a Unicode string with Python 3.x. So, for example, the following works fine:

```
a = '\u0394'
print(a)
Δ
```

But if I try to construct this by appending two strings, I have several problems:

```
a = '\u'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

a = '\\u'
b = '0394'
c = a + b
print(c)
\u4308
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\uhhhh` is an escape sequence, a *notation* used in string literals. You can't construct that notation from parts, at least not directly like that.

Generally, you'd use the [`chr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to produce individual characters from an integer instead:

```
>>> chr(int('0394', 16))
'Δ'
```

for example, where I first interpreted the hex string `0394` as an integer in base 16.

If you **must** generate the Python string literal escape notation, use `codecs.decode()` with the `unicode_escape` codec:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> r'\u' + '0394'
'\\u0394'
>>> codecs.decode(r'\u' + '0394', 'unicode_escape')
'Δ'
```